# Can private data become public in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

My question referred to private data usage in Hyperledger fabric: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data-arch.html?highlight=private%20data

Am I right that this is some special type of data, which can have live period in terms of blocks and may be distributed only to specified peers of channel and query by only specified peers of channel?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Slight clarification, private data is only distributed to the peers of organizations specified in the private data distribution policy. See more background in the in the [key concepts documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private-data/private-data.html).